# nltk.concordance gives maximum of 25 lines, no matter how i change that argument

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

So i started to learn NLP via nltk book and it seems i immediately ran into a problem nobody mentioned before.

Let's import data from nltk.book just as the book says:

```
from nltk.book import *
```

Now i want to continue with examples from the book:

```
text1.concordance("monstrous")
```

Gives me:

```
Displaying 11 of 11 matches:
ong the former , one was of a most monstrous size . ... This came towards us ,
ON OF THE PSALMS . " Touching that monstrous bulk of the whale or ork we have r
ll over with a heathenish array of monstrous clubs and spears . Some were thick
d as you gazed , and wondered what monstrous cannibal and savage could ever hav
that has survived the flood ; most monstrous and most mountainous ! That Himmal
they might scout at Moby Dick as a monstrous fable , or still worse and more de
th of Radney .'" CHAPTER 55 Of the monstrous Pictures of Whales . I shall ere l
ing Scenes . In connexion with the monstrous pictures of whales , I am strongly
ere to enter upon those still more monstrous stories of them which are to be fo
ght have been rummaged out of this monstrous cabinet there is no telling . But
of Whale - Bones ; for Whales of a monstrous size are oftentimes cast up dead u
```

So far, so good. Now i want to know concordance for word `whale` in Moby Dick.

```
text1.concordance("whale")
Displaying 25 of 25 matches:
s , and to teach them by what name a whale - fish is to be called in our tongue
t which is not true ." -- HACKLUYT " WHALE . ... Sw . and Dan . HVAL . This ani
ulted ." -- WEBSTER ' S DICTIONARY " WHALE . ... It is more immediately from th
ISH . WAL , DUTCH . HWAL , SWEDISH . WHALE , ICELANDIC . WHALE , ENGLISH . BALE
HWAL , SWEDISH . WHALE , ICELANDIC . WHALE , ENGLISH . BALEINE , FRENCH . BALLE
least , take the higgledy - piggledy whale statements , however authentic , in
 dreadful gulf of this monster ' s ( whale ' s ) mouth , are immediately lost a
 patient Job ." -- RABELAIS . " This whale ' s liver was two cartloads ." -- ST
 Touching that monstrous bulk of the whale or ork we have received nothing cert
 of oil will be extracted out of one whale ." -- IBID . " HISTORY OF LIFE AND D
ise ." -- KING HENRY . " Very like a whale ." -- HAMLET . " Which to secure , n
restless paine , Like as the wounded whale to shore flies thro ' the maine ." -
. OF SPERMA CETI AND THE SPERMA CETI WHALE . VIDE HIS V . E . " Like Spencer '
t had been a sprat in the mouth of a whale ." -- PILGRIM ' S PROGRESS . " That
EN ' S ANNUS MIRABILIS . " While the whale is floating at the stern of the ship
e ship called The Jonas - in - the - Whale . ... Some say the whale can ' t ope
 in - the - Whale . ... Some say the whale can ' t open his mouth , but that is
 masts to see whether they can see a whale , for the first discoverer has a duc
 for his pains . ... I was told of a whale taken near Shetland , that had above
oneers told me that he caught once a whale in Spitzbergen that was white all ov
2 , one eighty feet in length of the whale - bone kind came in , which ( as I w
n master and kill this Sperma - ceti whale , for I could never hear of any of t
 . 1729 . "... and the breath of the whale is frequendy attended with such an i
ed with hoops and armed with ribs of whale ." -- RAPE OF THE LOCK . " If we com
contemptible in the comparison . The whale is doubtless the largest animal in c
```

Whait, it can't be right. There is no way word "whale" is only occurs 25 times in Moby Dick. How about word "it"?

```
text1.concordance("it")
Displaying 25 of 25 matches:
```

Ok, lets increase amount of lines shown:

```
text1.concordance("it", lines=100)
Displaying 25 of 25 matches:
```

How about decreasing it?

```
text1.concordance("it", lines=10)
Displaying 10 of 25 matches:
```

It wants me to believe there is only 25 occurrences of the word "it"?
While this is definitely a malfunction, it gets even worse with `width` argument (it does not take it into account at all).

**System i use nltk with:**

Win 10 64 bit;

Python 3.6.5 32 bit

**What's going on and how can i fix that?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a bug with NLTK 3.3.

In the [source code](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html#ConcordanceIndex.print_concordance), the line

```
concordance_list = self.find_concordance(word, width=80, lines=25)
```

forces the results to be <= 25 lines with width <= 80 and should be

```
concordance_list = self.find_concordance(word, width=width, lines=lines)
```

The simplest workaround would be to downgrade your NLTK installation to version 3.2 (in which `concordance` has the expected behaviour).

Comment: Now we're talking! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the catch and the PR! Sorry about the previous comment, didn't read the code and answer properly (while I was waking up). There's was some bad function design when the `concordance_list()` was implemented. And the PR you've created has a missing edit that needs some change to the `find_concordance`, thus the unittest failure.

Comment: I think the exact line is 
`lines = min(lines, len(concordance_list))`